# Why doesn't device_create return error when a file already exists?

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, linux-device-driver, device-driver, chardev

I am writing a PCI driver with a character device for an interface (Linux 4.9.13). Here's the scenario that bothers me:

1. Run `touch /dev/foo0` which creates a normal file in the `/dev` directory.
2. Load the driver module. Here's a pseudo code representing what happens there (pretty standard character device registration):

   ```
   // When the module is initialized:
   alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 256, "foo");
   class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "foo");

   // Later, when a suitable PCI device is connected the probe function 
   // calls the following functions:
   cdev_init(dev->md_cdev, &fops);
   dev->md_devnum = MKDEV(major, 0 + index);
   res = cdev_add(dev->md_cdev, dev->md_devnum, 1);
   dev->md_sysfsdev = device_create(class, 0, dev->md_devnum, 0, "foo%d", index);
   ```

   Details:

   - `index` is just another free index

What seems weird to me is nothing raises an error that there is already a `/dev/foo0` file which is not a character device. I do check all the errors (I think so) but I omitted related code for the sake of conciseness. Everything works as expected if I do not run `touch /dev/foo0`. Otherwise, I can neither read nor write to the device.

Why is it so? Shouldn't `device_create` return an error or at least create `/dev/foo1` instead?

Comment: The file under `/dev` is created by `device_create()`, not by `cdev_add`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Good point. Thanks. I'll check my code one more time then.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Nah, I check for `device_create` errors with `IS_ERR` and it does not fail. Wel...

Comment: Shouldn't *udev* take care about such scenario?

Comment: @0andriy You're probably right - that's what I've heard recently. I've not got time to confirm it though.